# Example for explaining object-oriented concepts

Tags: object-oriented

What are some *good* examples for illustrating the concepts of object-oriented programming? I'm talking about sample classes, classes that would have inheritance, overriding, etc.

The only one I can ever think of is of animals. A base `Animal` class, with `Cow` that have a different `makeCry` method or something like that. It sucks. What do you guys use?

Comment: Are you actually trying to teach this to new programmers, old programmers without OOP experience, or non-programmers?

Comment: No, I wish that was my job :). I'm only curious as to what others use.

Comment: OOP prism is not the best object to look through at the real world.

Comment: my favorite example for illustrating the concepts of object-oriented programming is _POS system_ case study in Larman's [Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design...](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0131489062)

Comment: This question reads as a poll; there isn't any means to differentiate one answer as better than another.  Polls are not a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic set of objects I've always seen is Vehicle (base), Car, Truck, Airplane.

Edited to expand on the objects.

Vehicle could have a method `numberOfWheels`, which returns an integer.  The Car `numberOfWheels` would return 4.  The Truck `numberOfWheels` could return 4, 6, 10, or 18, depending on the type of truck.  The Airplane `numberOfWheels` would return 17  for a jet airliner (I think).

Another method could be `engineType`, which returns a String.  The Car `engineType` would return either "gasoline" or "diesel".  The Truck `engineType` would return either "gasoline" or "diesel".  The Airplane `engineType` would return either "gasoline" or "jet".

You could certainly come up with more methods that vehicles have in common.

Comment: What are some methods and properties? What is overloaded?

Comment: Methods (Stop(), Start(), Accelerate(), etc)  each would have a different implementation.  Throw in a sail boat to really mess things up...

Answer (score 7):

Off the top of my head: You're making a game, something like SimCity.

You've got a base class called `building`, and subclasses called `residential`, `commercial`, `utility`, or whatnot.

All buildings have a location, value, and land-tax (you're mayor remember). 
Residential buildings provide living space.
Commercial buildings provide working space.
Utility buildings provide services.

The `calculateValue` and `calculateLandTax` functions would be handled differently for residential and commercial buildings.

Answer (score 2):

I once had to teach children these concepts. The projects were mostly simple video-games which lent itself very nicely to basic OOD/OOP. You had `Sprite` which was a root of a hierarchy. It would have attributes such as `size`, `speed`, and `health` and these would often be overriden to have different values in different subclasses. Common methods that all `Sprites` had (but sometimes overrode) would be things like `move`. Then you had subclasses such as `GoodGuy`, `BadGuy`, and sometimes we'd have a `Scenery` class (for sprites that just moved around in the background). Sometimes `BadGuy` would have further subclasses such as `BossBadGuy` and `BigBossBadGuy` which would override some of the `BadGuy` methods (such as `attack`, `die`, `respawn`).

Answer (score 2):

The best example I know of is actors on a stage in a play - it also helps you avoid ending up in the inheritance tar pit.

Say we have the play [Julius Caesar](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/playmenu.php?WorkID=juliuscaesar) from William Shakespeare. You could implement it with a bunch of Actor `classes`, from which e.g. the [Calpurnia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calpurnia_Pisonis) `class` is derived. You could have multiple Calpurnia `classes` (say for different actresses knowing the role of Calpurnia, each with different strength an weaknesses, but all of them able to play - more or less - properly their role).

When during a play of Julius Caesar Calpurnia says the line:

> What mean you, Caesar? think you to walk forth? 
>   You shall not stir out of your house to-day.

The instance of the Calpurnia class (= `object`) sends a `message` (= calls a `method` on) an `instance` of the Julius Caesar class. Which reacts according to the script (= `algorithm` implemented in the called method) with the line:

> The things that threaten'd me ne'er look'd but on my back; when they shall see 
>   The face of Caesar, they are vanished.

The instance of the Calpurnia class though has no idea how the Caesar object creates this answer (= `encapsulation`) and everyone is perfectly aware, that this is not the real Julius Caesar (or Calpurnia) standing on the stage, but actors representing reasonably romanticized versions of the historic persons (= `abstraction`).

Another participating class in this scenario is the `Spectator` class. They make heavy use of the fact, that all roles belong to the `Actor` class and as such instances of them can be watched, listened too or applauded – or booed – irrespective of their concrete subclass (= polymorphism).

And of course there are thousands of different ways on how'd you be able to represent a play(house) in an object oriented fashion...